# Object reference not set to an instance of an object on post method foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a page that has various fields to fill in as part of the form.

I also want to be able to gather 5 sets of information for example friends you want to join on the same form.

In the razor view Ive managed to display the same input box 5 times to allow a maximum of 4 people to be added however I don't know how to pass this data separately back to the controller to enable an individual record to be saved for each of the 4 boxes.

Heres the bit of razor code Ive used:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1">
    @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Friend) @i
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Friend)      
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Is there a way I can post the information back to the controller reference the value of i in the razor code? I need to know how to deal with the data in the post method, the suggested duplicate question doesnt show this.

Heres the start of my post controller that will handle one copy of friend

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddFriend(AddFriendViewModel viewModel)
    {
        foreach(var f in model.FriendList)
         {
                var friend =
                new Friend
                {
                    Friend = f.Friend
                };
          db.Friends.Add(friend);
          db.SaveChanges();
         }

        return View("Success")
    }
```

However when I run it I get the following error on the in section of the foreach

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: What would you want the value of `@i`? Your model needs a property which is a collection and your bind to the collection.

Comment: Editing a list of objects [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696988/mvc-editing-a-list-of-objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696988/mvc-editing-a-list-of-objects)

Comment: Also show your model(s). What is typeof property `Friend`? The solution varies if its `string` or a complex object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess all you need to do is input 5 friends on same form. Using a List<> for friends would be a good solution.

Model

```
public class MyModel
{
    public List<Friend> FriendList {get; set;}
}

public class Friend
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Razor

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1">
    @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FriendList[i].Name)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FriendList[i].Name)      
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
    foreach(var f in model.FriendList)
    {
      db.Friends.Add(f);
      db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

PS : Your code may vary depending upon your friend model.

Comment: Would you be able to put some of the post controller code up please?

Comment: Ive updated the post to show a basic post method that will add one friend

Comment: I've added code for controller. If four db Friend table and Friend ViewModel are different. Just map the properties before saving then.

Comment: Thanks @ShishirKushwaha Ive updated my post to show the post controller with your answer and my mapping, however I now get the object not set to an instance error, any ideas?

Comment: @PhillSanders Please post the classes Friend and AddFriendViewModel as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure. You can do this with or without razor.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Friend) @i
        <input type="text" name="Friend[@i]" value="@Model.Friend[i]" />      
    </div>
}
```

And your controller to receive data should be look like this,

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
    // model.Friend should be a list of string
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Howver its the controller side I'm struggling with to, apologies but I'm still new to mvc. How would I get my data in the controller?

Comment: @PhillSanders, Ok. Do you know how to pass your data to your controller on form submit? If no, please create a chat room when you get time. We can have a chat session.

Comment: Ive updated the post to show a basic post method that will add one friend